# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'athlete_profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to make a page where i can display an athlete's profile to them by using their primary key as a refernce but I get an error as follows:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 4.1.7
Python Version: 3.11.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'events',
 'userty']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\templates\base.html, error at line 81
   Reverse for 'athlete_profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/profile/athlete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
   71 : </head>
   72 : <body>
   73 :   <nav>
   74 :     <div>
   75 :       <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Combat-Con</a>
   76 :     </div>
   77 :     <div>
   78 :       <a href="{% url 'events:event_list' %}">Events</a>
   79 :       {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   80 :         {% if user.is_athlete %}
   81 :             <a href=" {% url 'userty:athlete_profile' pk=athlete.pk %} ">Athlete Profile</a>
   82 :         {% elif user.is_host %}
   83 :           <a href="{% url 'userty:host_profile' pk=user.host.pk %}">Host Profile</a>
   84 :         {% endif %}
   85 :       <a href="{% url 'userty:user_logout' %}">Logout</a>
   86 :       {% else %}
   87 :         <a href="{% url 'userty:register' %}">Register</a>
   88 :         <a href="{% url 'userty:login' %}">Login</a>
   89 :       {% endif %}
   90 :     </div>
   91 :   </nav>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\userty\views.py", line 15, in home
    return render(request, 'home.html')
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 321, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 321, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 471, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'athlete_profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['users/profile/athlete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

my athlete_profile view is as follows:

```
@login_required
def athlete_profile(request,pk):
    if request.user.is_athlete:
        #athlete = request.user.athlete(pk=pk)
        #athlete = Athlete.objects.get(user=request.user, pk=pk)
        athlete = get_object_or_404(Athlete,pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'users/athlete_profile', {'athlete': athlete})
    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

urls.py as follows:

```
path('profile/athlete/<int:pk>/', views.athlete_profile, name='athlete_profile'),
```

```
User models:
    class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    is_athlete = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_host = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Athlete(models.Model):
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
WEIGHT_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Straw Weight', 'Straw Weight'),
    ('Fly Weight', 'Fly Weight'),
    ('Bantam Weight', 'Bantam Weight'),
)
user = models.OneToOneField('userty.MyUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
email = models.EmailField(null=True, default='example@example.com')
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='athlete_pics/', null=True, blank=True)
contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
date_of_birth = models.DateField()
age = models.IntegerField()
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
weight_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=WEIGHT_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
fighting_style = models.CharField(max_length=100)
club_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
coach_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
record = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

**EDIT**
athelete_profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Athlete Profile</h1>
  <img src="{{ athlete.profile_picture.url }}" alt="Profile Picture">
  <p>Name: {{ athlete.name }}</p>
  <p>Contact Number: {{ athlete.contact_number }}</p>
  <p>Date of Birth: {{ athlete.date_of_birth }}</p>
  <p>Age: {{ athlete.age }}</p>
  <p>Gender: {{ athlete.gender }}</p>
  <p>Height: {{ athlete.height }}</p>
  <p>Weight: {{ athlete.weight }}</p>
  <p>Weight Category: {{ athlete.weight_category }}</p>
  <p>Fighting Style: {{ athlete.fighting_style }}</p>
  <p>Club Name: {{ athlete.club_name }}</p>
  <p>Coach Name: {{ athlete.coach_name }}</p>
  <p>Record: {{ athlete.record }}</p>
  <a href="{% url 'userty:edit_athlete_profile' %}">Edit Profile</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I've tried using different functions to get athlete info (see the commented code in view function).
I have also tried using different fields like username, name, and contact number to get the Athlete object but all of them give me this error.

Comment: Can you share your custom User model?

Comment: Well, what is `users/athlete_profile` this in `render()` where is `.html`?

Comment: @SunderamDubey changes have been made

Comment: There should be `.html` in `render()`.

Comment: @SunderamDubey added `.html` in `render()` still getting the same error

Comment: In line no. 81 you have `href=" {% url 'userty:athlete_profile' pk=athlete.pk %} "`, not sure but I'd recommend you to remove an extra spaces from both sides, I mean trim it, so it should be `href="{% url 'userty:athlete_profile' pk=athlete.pk %}"`

Comment: @SunderamDubey those spaces were added by mistake

Answer (score 1):

You are reversing the `edit_athlete_profile` URL in the template here:

```
<a href="{% url 'userty:edit_athlete_profile' %}">Edit Profile</a>
```

without passing an argument for the URL kwarg `pk`.

You haven't provided your full urls, but from what you provided I can guess the problem:

```
path('profile/athlete/<int:pk>/', views.athlete_profile, name='athlete_profile'),
```

-> this means that Django expects a URL parameter named `pk` of the type `int`. You need to pass this along when reversing URLs, e.g.:

```
<a href="{% url 'userty:edit_athlete_profile' pk=athlete.pk %}">Edit Profile</a>
```

So I suspect you have a similar URL pattern but then for the edit route.

Comment: i made the change in `athlete_profile.html` the error is still not solved

Comment: your traceback actually has the information: `In template C:\SHRUTI\SEM_6\PROJECT\COMBAT_CON_F\templates\base.html` -> apparently this route is also present in your `base.html` template.

Comment: link was specified in base.html as follows: `<a href=" {% url 'userty:athlete_profile' pk=athlete.pk %} ">Athlete Profile</a>`